How to Enable User Assisgned Managed Identity authentication Between Azure Bot and Azure Kubernetes Service?
I have an Azure bot created using a user-assigned managed identity via the Azure portal. The bot's code is written in C# and utilizes the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK. The application is deployed on an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster.
I would like to know the steps to enable a managed identity connection between my bot and AKS. Specifically, how can I ensure that the bot can authenticate and access Azure resources securely using its managed identity while running in AKS?
Getting following error : [Managed Identity] Authentication unavailable. No response received from the managed Identity endpoint.
I have followed this documentation for my implementaiton but this is for Azure app service => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp.
I Have Done So Far:

Created a user-assigned managed identity in Azure.

Configured the Azure bot service to use the managed identity for authentication (UserAssignedMSI Type).

Deployed the code in aks with workload identity by providing created user managed identity.


As per the documentation, the Azure bot code will work without any changes if you configure it to use a user-assigned managed identity (USMI).
To set up your bot correctly, follow these guidelines:

Bot Type: Set the bot type to "UserAssignedMSI" to specify that the bot will authenticate using a user-assigned managed identity.

Bot ID: The BotID should be the client ID of the created user-assigned managed identity.

Bot Password: Leave the BotPassword field empty, as it is not required when using a user-assigned managed identity.

Bot Tenant: The BotTenant should be set to the tenant ID of your Azure Active Directory.



You can reference this template https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit/tree/dev/templates/ts/default-bot/infra which uses app service to host the bot. To enable the connection between azure bot service and app service, the managed identity is added to the app service, see line.
For AKS you might also need to add the managed identity to your AKS, this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#enable-a-user-assigned-managed-identity might be helful.
